# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory for Ruby application deployed by passenger

Tags: ruby, .htaccess, redirect, passenger

My Ruby on Rails project is on justhost server. When I am creating there ruby project, it is creating this in folder rails_apps by default.
For my project, I have created symlinks.
**ln -s ~/rails_apps/webworth/public ~/public_html/webworth**
And
**ln -s ~/rails_apps/webworth ~/public_html/webworth_app** [Purpose of this symlink just for browsing files by ftp client]

I created .htaccess file in ~/rails_apps/webworth/public directory. Below is the .htaccess code

```
Options -MultiViews  
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on  
RailsEnv development  
RailsBaseURI /webworth  
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home5/worthgur/ruby/gems
```

and one .htaccess file in ~/public_html. Below is the code:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default  
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php  

RewriteEngine on  
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  
RewriteBase /  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?webworth.com [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webworth/ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "webworth\/$1" [L]
```

Everything is working proper with these structure of .htaccess files except one problem. Extra text is appending to all urls in my project i.e "webworth" for all links generated by routes.rb file. And I want to remove this extra text "webworth" from all URL's.

```
Now urls are generating for example in this manner.
http://webworth.com/webworth/tags/smartphones
while it should be http://webworth.com/tags/smartphones.
```

This extra text i.e "webworth" was added previously for the folder that has to be accessed since it was not in the document root for the site and because of this extra text, extra text is appending to all URL's generated by routes.rb file thru ~/rails_apps/webworth/public/.htaccess file [Reason: RailsBaseURI /webworth]

I guess this can be fixed by changing ***RailsBaseURI /webworth*** to ***RailsBaseURI /*** in ~/rails_apps/webworth/public/.htaccess file.
I did that and I am sure I could not write proper commands in ~/public_html/.htaccess file so that I can redirect the traffic from the public_html to the symlink (webworth) for my site. I used many options but couldn't figure out how it will work. Please help to write ~/public_html/.htaccess file properly to redirect the traffic from public_html folder to my symlink(webworth).
Justhost suggested this link: [How to host the Primary Domain from a subfolder](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/347). But still I could not figure out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with justhost and I solved it without adding any redirect. 
I set my rails app public folder to be the main site public folder.

- I renamed the original "public_html" to "public_html_backup", just in case.
- Added a symlink `ln -s ~/myRailsApp/public ~/public_html`
- in my htaccess I changed `RailsBaseURI /myRailsApp` to `RailsBaseURI /`, resulting in:

`<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
      Options -MultiViews
      PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
      RailsEnv production
      RackBaseURI /
      SetEnv GEM_HOME /yourUserPath.../ruby/gems
</IfModule>`

I hope this can help you. 
Cheers

Comment: Doesn't this prevent you from having subdomains and and test environments that would otherwise have symlinks in public_html folder?